# How did my textbook simplify this differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm trying to find a general solution for a problem, and I've been following this example so far and understanding, but my textbook made a jump that I can't figure out:

[image]

I don't know how $x^{-2}{dy\over dx}-2x^{-3}y=cosx$ got to be ${d\over dx}(x^{-2}y)=cosx$

What did they do?

Comment: $\dfrac{d}{dx} \left(x^{-2} y\right) = -2 x^{-3} y + x^{-2} \dfrac{dy}{dx}$ by the product and chain rule. They just went in reverse, in other words, they know the derivative of that expression can be represented by that simpler expression. Clear?

Comment: @Moo Ah, yes. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They just observed. You can see:$$\frac{d(x^{-2}y)}{dx}=x^{-2}\frac{dy}{dx}-2x^{-3}y$$

Answer (score 0):

In this type of equations one term containing $y$ and other containing its $\frac{dy}{dx}$. So it means product rule.

We got product rule $\frac{d}{dx} (y \cdot  \, \underline{\hspace{5mm}})$

Now as term containing $\frac{dy}{dx}$ has derivative of $y$ so other term with it is the second term used for product rule. You can verify.

Term with $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is $x^{-2}$. Now we find its derivative.

$= -2x^{-3}$

And we can see term with $y$ has this.

So we fill $x^{-2}$ in our product rule.

$\frac{d}{dx}(y\cdot x^{-2})$

Comment: I want to show space. Can somebody help me.

Comment: What do you mean show space?

Comment: Like this?  $\left(y \cdot \underline{\hspace{5mm}}\right)$

Comment: Yes like that..

Comment: `$(y \cdot \, \underline{\hspace{5mm}})$`

Comment: @tilper thank you very much.